# how to change the slider thumb image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, custom-controls, slider

I have to create my own customized slider. I am trying to change the thumb image,background of the slider and in the some test like slide to unlock.
I have tried like this but its not working

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 219.0, 323.0, 20.0);
UISlider *myslider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[myslider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[myslider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myslider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderThumb@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

myslider.minimumValue = 0.0;
myslider.maximumValue = 50.0;
myslider.continuous = YES;
myslider.value = 15.0;
[self.view addSubview:myslider];
```

But in this the size of thumb pic is very big.How to reduce the thumb pic size....and how to give the slider background and text.Please help me out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set the background colour of the slider, I would presume that you can set the property `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider background"]];`

Also, images that have the appending ending of `@2x`, mean that they are twice the size of the standard copy. This is for retina displays only, you should not use it in a `UIImage` on a standard (legacy) device. Try setting the image name to `@"sliderThumb.png"` instead, as long as you have the legacy copy of the image.

Answer (score 16):

```
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_slider_oragne.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.3 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_strap_gry.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.3 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: it causes bugs if thumb has a different size

Answer (score 4):

Just provide a different size of sliderThumb@2x.png and all we work itself out.